# Specify Active Directory Domain Controller via DirectoryEntry or DirectorySearcher?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, domaincontroller, directorysearcher

I can specify the domain controller when I want to search through AD using this:

```
$principalContext  = New-Object 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext'([System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Domain, $DomainControllerIpAddress, $Container)
```

How can I specify the domain controller using a `DirectoryEntry` or `DirectorySearcher`?

Comment: this may be related to your question: http://serverfault.com/a/399484

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Multiple constructor overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.directorysearcher(v=vs.110).aspx) for the `DirectorySearcher` take a `DirectoryEntry` as it's argument, and you can target a specific server when creating one:

```
# [adsi] is a type accelerator for the DirectoryEntry class
$Entry = [adsi]"LDAP://dc01.domain.tld/OU=MyContainer,DC=domain,DC=tld"

# [adsisearcher] is a type accelerator for the DirectorySearcher class
$Searcher = [adsisearcher]$Entry
```